# Compare Unique Transactional Data Week-over-Week

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a huge transactional table that works as an archive for our orders.

The structure is like this:

```
Archive Date    Order
08.02.2021  45922
08.02.2021  45753
08.02.2021  45752
15.02.2021  45922
15.02.2021  45753
15.02.2021  45752
15.02.2021  45754
```

On every week on Monday, I put a new snapshot of our order table into this table.

This table is linked to our department dimensions table and our calendar table.

Now I would like to determine

How many Orders (unique) are listed per week

How many new Orders are listed compared to the previous week

How many Orders have left/ are missing compared to previous week

This is my approach until now:

```
#Orders = 
    DISTINCTCOUNT( 'tblOrders'[Orders] )

#Orders -1week = 
CALCULATE (
    [#Orders,
    DATEADD('Calendar'[Date], -7, DAY))

#New Orders
VAR _Entry = IF([#Orders]<>1,BLANK(), [#Orders] - [#Orders -1week])
RETURN 
_Entry
```

But if I use a Department as a Dimension in a Matrix, then I get a '0' as a result.

Comment: How is your department related to this archive table?

Comment: Ahh, good point! Thanks for that hint! We have a Order Master Table where all Ordersnumbers have a corresponding Department Key